# Simultaneous equation for logarithms

Tags: logarithms

Solve the pair of simultaneous equations:

\begin{align}\log(x-y) &=0\tag{1} \\
 2 \log y&=\log(21+x)\tag{2}\end{align}

Comment: When is log(a)=0? Also do you know when is $\log a=\log b$?

Comment: Hint: exponentiate both sides of both equations.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, please try to make the title more descriptive, there are a lot of questions about simultaneous equations for logarithms.

Answer (score 2):

$\log(x-y)=0$ means that $x-y=1$ then $x=1+y$

$2\log y=\log(22+y)$ we will use the operation $10^x$ for both side we get that
$y^2=22+y$. Now it is easy to find $y$ (you have to choose the positive solution), and $x=1+y$.

Comment: But its $\log(21+x)$. Also I believe $\log$ means natural logarithm. EDIT: Ah yes. So you should get $y^2=22+y$

Comment: x=1+y so 21+x=22+y. I also thought it is the natural logarithm but it seems that the answer is very "ugly" so I believe it is actually of basis 10. yes you are right thats $y^2$

Comment: You can instead just say that $2\log y=\log y^2$ and $\log a=\log b$ implies $a=b$ to avoid choosing a base.

Comment: you also need $y>0,x>y$

Comment: yea we get 2 solutions for y, and need to choose the positive one, however x=y+1 so x>y.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}\log(x-y) &=0 \tag 1 \\
2 \log y&=\log(21+x) \tag 2 \end{align}

I am posting because I am surprised at the seemingly needless complexity of some posted answers.

From $\log(x-y)=0$ you get $x-y=1.$

From $2\log y = \log(21+x)$ you get $\log(y^2) = \log(21+x),$ and then $y^2 = 21+x.$

So you have:
\begin{align}
x-y & = 1 \tag 3 \\
y^2 & = 21 + x \tag 4
\end{align}
From $(3)$ you get $y=x-1.$ So put $x-1$ in place of $y$ in $(4)$ and get a quadratic equation.

Or else put $y+1$ in place of $x$ in $(4)$ and get a quadratic equation.

There is no need to know the base of the logarithms as long as they're both the same.

Comment: Please can you further more on this. I need help.

Comment: @JohnstonLeo : If $x-y=1$ then $x=y+1$ so you can put $y+1$ in place of $x$ in the other equation. The other equation is $y^2=21+x.$ So that becomes $y^2 = 21 + (y+1).$ That says $y^2 - y -22=0.$ That is a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0):

We have \begin{align}\log(x-y) &=0\tag{1} \\
2 \log y&=\log(21+x)\tag{2}\end{align}

Our first step is:

\begin{align}e^{\log(x-y)} &=e^0\tag{1} \\
&\Downarrow\\
x-y&=1\tag{3}\\\\
e^{2 \log y}&=e^{\log(21+x)}\tag{2}\\
&\Downarrow\\
y^2&=21+x\tag{4}\end{align}

Now we have two equations in terms on $x$ and $y$ which we can solve easily:

From equation $(3)$, we have \begin{align}y&=x-1\\
y^2&=(x-1)^2\\
&=x^2-2x+1\end{align}

Then, we put this into $(4)$ to find\begin{align}x^2-2x+1&=21+x\\
x^2-3x-20&=0\\
x&=\frac12\left(3\pm \sqrt{89}\right)\end{align}

We then solve $(3)$ for $y$:

\begin{align}y&=x-1\\
&=\frac12\left(3\pm \sqrt{89}\right)-1\\
&=\frac12\left(1\pm \sqrt{89}\right)\end{align}

Therefore, we get \begin{align}x=\frac12\left(3+ \sqrt{89}\right)&,y=\frac12\left(1+ \sqrt{89}\right)\\
x\approx-6.21699&,y\approx5.21699\end{align}

\begin{align}x=\frac12\left(3- \sqrt{89}\right)&,y=\frac12\left(1- \sqrt{89}\right)\\
x\approx-3.21699&,y\approx-4.21699\end{align}

Since we can't have a negative value for a logarithm, then we have to discount the second 'solution' as it would mean there was a negative value in equation $(2)$: $2\log y$

Therefore, our solution is:

\begin{align}x&=\frac12\left(3+ \sqrt{89}\right)\\
y&=\frac12\left(1+ \sqrt{89}\right)\end{align}